# Continuity equation for compressible fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, definition, flow, continuum-mechanics

A question is given as

> Consider a fluid of density $ \rho(x, y, z, t) $ which moves with velocity $v(x, y, z, t) $ without sources or sink. Show that $ \nabla \cdot \vec J + \frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t} = 0 ;$ where $ \vec J = \rho \vec v  \hspace{0.5 cm}$ ( $\vec v$ being velocity of fluid and $ \rho $ density).

In the solution it assumes, $ - \nabla \cdot \vec J $ is the change in $ \vec J$ within the volume element which should be equal to $ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ *(why equal?)*. I don't understand this part and I doubt if this question is correct. I think the question should be 
$$ \rho (\nabla \cdot \vec v) + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$$
Is the question correct? If it's correct help me to understand the solution (if it's right) or please provide me correct answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I) The [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) without sink and sources reads

$$\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\rho\vec v)   ~=~ 0.$$

Hint on how to derive it:

1. Establish first the [integral form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Integral_form) of the continuity equation for an arbitrary (sufficiently regular) 3D spatial integration region.
2. Next use the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition_of_divergence) of the 3D [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) to argue the [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Differential_form) of the continuity equation.

The continuity equation can be rewritten with the help of a [material derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative) $\frac{D \rho }{D t}$ as

$$\frac{D \rho }{D t} + \rho \nabla \cdot \vec v   ~=~ 0.$$

II) For an [incompressible fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow), the density $\rho$ of a certain fluid parcel does not change as a function of time,

$$\frac{D \rho }{D t}~=0.$$

If the density $\rho\neq 0$, an incompressible fluid then has a divergencefree flow

$$\nabla \cdot \vec v~=~0.$$

Comment: To quickly comment here, $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ is not primarily what defines an incompressible fluid; if a fluid can't be compressed, then it can't be decompressed either, and so $D\rho/Dt = 0$. Plugging that into the continuity equation you've rewritten, you get $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ as a consequence, since we assume $\rho > 0$ (i.e. matter exists in the system). I'm being nitpicky, but the point is that $D\rho/Dt = 0$ defines incompressibility, while the continuity equation establishes the equivalence $D\rho/Dt = 0 \leftrightarrow \nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$.

Comment: Hi @Erik. Thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer accordingly.